# What windows registry key I must use to install a delphi expert?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

I need to create a installer for a Delphi IDE expert, So I found these two registry keys

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Embarcadero\BDS\x.0\Known IDE Packages    
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Embarcadero\BDS\x.0\Known Packages
```

Which is the recomended key to install/Uninstall a  Delphi IDE Expert?

Answer (score 4):

`Known IDE Packages` is for packages that are used by the IDE itself (such as experts).

`Known Packages` is for packages that are used by projects (such as components and their design-time editors).

Comment: Additionally, DLL experts are under the `Experts` subkey.

Comment: Sorry @Remy but your suggestion doesn't work. also check ths [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8336924/why-my-delphi-ide-expert-is-not-initialized-when-use-the-known-ide-packages-ke)