# Why my Delphi IDE Expert is not initialized when use the "Known IDE Packages" Key?

Tags: delphi

I'm installing a BPL (without dll) Delphi Expert using this Windows registry key

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Embarcadero\BDS\x.0\Known IDE Packages
```

As suggest the answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8320125/what-windows-registry-key-i-must-use-to-install-a-delphi-expert), but the expert is not initializated by the delphi IDE. The expert only works when I use this key

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Embarcadero\BDS\x.0\Known Packages
```

What i'm missing? I need register the BPL (Package) in another place (Windows registry key) too ? I read the [`Erik’s Open Tools API FAQ`](http://www.gexperts.org/open-tools-api-faq/) but I can't found any resource or tip about the installation of a Delphi IDE Expert.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, you should not be using that key... Even if you did succeed in using that key, the expert services aren't initialized and available at that point. What is wrong with using the normal Known Packages key?

Comment: Because he got a wrong answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8320125/what-windows-registry-key-i-must-use-to-install-a-delphi-expert)

Comment: I'm just following the suggestion of my previous [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8320125/what-windows-registry-key-i-must-use-to-install-a-delphi-expert) where the recomendation was use `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Embarcadero\BDS\x.0\Known IDE Packages`

Comment: @Allen just told you it was, and he should know (he's on the Delphi team at Embarcadero). :)

Comment: @KenWhite, I know who is Allen Bauer, but [Remmy](http://stackoverflow.com/users/65863/remy-lebeau-teamb) (which is a Team B member) give me the opposed answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8320125/what-windows-registry-key-i-must-use-to-install-a-delphi-expert).

Comment: Remy is on [TeamB](htttp://teamb.cm), but TeamB are unpaid volunteers. Allen works on the **Delphi Development Team** at Embarcadero. Who do you think is probably right? :)

Answer (score 5):

If it is an IDE expert, why not use the

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Embarcadero\BDS\x.0\Experts
```

key directly?

Comment: I check that key and only has dll experts, I can register my BPL expert in that Key too?